# Failed the exuctute the login command. FreeBSD help

Tags: freebsd

I have installed FreeBSD onto my system and I have to install XForce and XOrg but got the error. I have also installed Slim. Then I rebooted and got the issues there. Would love it if I get some help. I have reinstalled the system but got the error. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

Thanks, Jonathan Steadman.
Video: https://youtu.be/1UrGQO8qM0c
I followed this guide: https://leonardcucos.com/how-to-install-freebsd-13-with-xfce-4-2021/

Please help. :(
Update fixed the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like your XFCE desktop doesn't get started by Slim. Have you created the .xinitrc file? Run this command and replace  with the user you've created

```
echo 'exec startxfce4' > /home/<username>/.xinitrc
```

I also see that the guide states that you install slim-themes. Some suggestions point to editing `/usr/local/etc/slim.conf` and changing `current_theme default` `to current_theme fbsd`

Comment: thanks I was able to get it to work at the end. :)